# WPF DataTemplate in resource, binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have below DataGrid(simplified)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Something}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding A}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding B}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

Is there any way to move DataTemplate to resources and reuse it for different properties so I don't have to copy and paste DataTemplate for every property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pragmatic solution would be to define templates on resource level and wrap them in a 'ContentPresenter' in each column. You still have to define a template for each column explicitly. Still, you can manage the templates in one place and quickly see to which properties your columns are bound.

```xml
<DataGrid>
     <!-- Templates in a single place in resources -->
     <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditCellTemplate">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGrid.Resources>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding A}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding A}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EditCellTemplate}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding B}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding B}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EditCellTemplate}" />
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: For me, the key from your answer that got me functioning was setting the `Content="{Binding}"` on the `ContentPresenter`. I was using `DataContext="{Binding}"` which didn't work, but after changing it to Content I got the binding to finally work.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Something}">
      <DataGrid.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:key="MyTemplate">
             <Grid>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" 
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" 
                                    >
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </Datagrid>
```

But then you need to rethink binding logic, as you will need to use cell datacontext in the same template for all the columns.

Comment: As far as I understand {Binding} binds whole object to template , so how I can  bind specific property to template column?

Comment: @blackcat there is nothing stopping you from having two datatemplates inside the resources (one for when binding to A and one when B), still better than four.

Comment: @adminSoftDK still I need four datatemplates (edit and display where I will have {Binding A} and {Binding B}), I am looking generic solution for this

Comment: @adminSoftDK make all your bound classes adhere to an `Interface` which the template only binds to, that way one only needs one template per many different object types.